# Minimize maximum absolute difference in pairs of numbers

Tags: algorithm

**The problem statement**:
Give `n` variables and `k` pairs. The variables can be distinct by assigning a value from 1 to `n` to each variable. Each pair `p` contain 2 variables and let the absolute difference between 2 variables in `p` is `abs(p)`. Define the upper bound of difference is `U=max(Abs(p)|every p)`.

Find an assignment that minimize `U`.

```
Limit:   
n<=100  
k<=1000
```

Each variable appear at least 2 times in list of pairs.

```
A problem instance:  
Input  
n=9, k=12  
1 2 (meaning pair x1 x2)   
1 3  
1 4  
1 5  
2 3  
2 6 
3 5   
3 7    
3 8  
3 9 
6 9  
8 9  
Output:  
1 2 5 4 3 6 7 8 9  
(meaning x1=1,x2=2,x3=5,...)
```

**Explaination:** An assignment of `x1=1,x2=2,x3=3,...` will result in `U=6` (3 9 has greastest abs value). The output assignment will get `U=4`, the minimum value (changed pair: `3 7 => 5 7, 3 8 => 5 8`, etc. and 3 5 isn't changed. In this case, `abs(p)<=4` for every pair).

**There is an important point**: To achieve the best assignments, the variables in the pairs that have greatest abs must be change.
Base on this, I have thought of a greedy algorithm:

```
1)Assign every x to default assignment (x(i)=i)  
2)Locate pairs that have largest abs and x(i)'s contained in them.  
3)For every i,j: Calculate U. Swap value of x(i),x(j). Calculate U'. If U'<U, stop and repeat step 3. If U'>=U for every i,j, end and output the assignment.
```

However, this method has a major pitfall, if we need an assignment like this:

```
x(a)<<x(b), x(b)<<x(c), x(c)<<x(a)
```

, we have to swap in 2 steps, like: `x(a)<=>x(b)`, then `x(b)<=>x(c)`, then there is a possibility that `x(b)<<x(a)` in first step has its abs become larger than U and the swap failed.
Is there any efficient algorithm to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't see a question here, nor code written, or an explanation of a problem. Instead I see what looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: So you want to minimize the maximum difference within each pair?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_bandwidth  (NP complete, even for special cases). It looks like people run http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuthill-McKee_algorithm when they need to do this to try and turn a sparse matrix into a banded diagonal matrix.